# Error while creating a package to submit to windows phone 8.1 store

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to package an app to submit to windows phone 8.1 store but I'm getting the following error :

> All languages specified in the Language attribute of the Resource
>   element in the app manifest must be supported by the Windows Store.
>   The value of the Resource element is comprised of the value from the
>   Default Language field in the App Manifest Designer and a generated
>   the list of languages based on localized resources in the project. The
>   list of Windows Store app languages is available at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=223184.

- I'm not using any languages other than the default language(en-US) in my app.
- I'm also not using any multi language toolkit.

So I'm stuck here I've tried packaging another app and it works so there is no problem with my account or VS I guess.

Also I've tried creating a new project and added the old code but the problem still exists.

Edit: 
The package manifest contains

```
<Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
 </Resources>
```

Comment: Can you open the packagemanifest with xml editor and check what value/values are present inside the Language attribute?

Comment: I've edited it in the question

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by changing

```
<Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
 </Resources>
```

To

```
<Resources>
    <Resource Language="en-US" />
 </Resources>
```

Comment: removing this like `<Resource Language="x-generate" />` from the manifest fixed it for me. Thanks